# Android SurfaceView taking all the space in layout

Tags: android, layout, surfaceview

I have this layout:

```
<LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:orientation="vertical">


                <SurfaceView
                    android:id="@+id/Preview"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="20dp" />


                <VideoView
                    android:id="@+id/videoView"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="20dp"/>
            </LinearLayout>
```

The SurfaceView and the VideoView should share the available space equally, and they do if I put the VideoView first. When I do it like above, the SurfaceView takes up all the space in the layout. 
How could I prevent this without giving specific dps for width and height?

Answer (score 0):

Both of your `Views` are filling the parent as the attribute states: `android:layout_width=fill_parent`

To equally divide the screen so you two views are next to each other you can use weights:

```
        <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical">


            <SurfaceView
                android:id="@+id/Preview"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
                android:layout_weight="1" />


            <VideoView
                android:id="@+id/videoView"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
                android:layout_weight="1" />
        </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

you must add layout_weight=1

```
<LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:orientation="vertical">


                <SurfaceView
                    android:id="@+id/Preview"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="20dp" 
                    android:layout_weight="1"/>


                <VideoView
                    android:id="@+id/videoView"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"/>
            </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: This makes the video visible, but very small. If i increase the weight, the video gets bigger to a certain point, but never really takes the currect space, unfortunately. 
Thanks for the idea!

Comment: you have to remove margin, also the videoView keep the aspect ratio of the video, so on most time it will not fill all the available space.

Answer (score 0):

Try with "weightSum=2". Also split the margins in both views!

```
<LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
                android:weightSum="2">


            <SurfaceView
                android:id="@+id/Preview"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"/>


            <VideoView
                android:id="@+id/videoView"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"/>
        </LinearLayout>
```